# Matplotlib Enlarge the space between x-axis labels

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

1. I want to increase the space between the labels in the x-axis so that they wont stay side by side.
2. Is there anyway I could "drag" the plot horizontally, its like what I could do in the excel when I drag the plot horizontally to the right, the entire plot gets larger.

Here is the current screenshot:
[image]

I did use code like ax.xaxis.get_children()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GiZH.png).set_size(100), but its not working.

```
               import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
               import numpy as np
               line = plt.figure()    
               plt.plot(x,y, 'r-',marker='o', color='b')
               plt.grid(True)
               plt.xticks(x, Quickdatres,rotation="vertical")

               ax=plt.subplot()
               ax.xaxis.get_children()[1].set_size(100)
               for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:  
               label.set_visible(False)   

               plt.show()
```

Quickdatres contains all labels for x-axis. Thx!

Comment: I think the interval is set automatically by the `plt.plot` function. It tries to even the interval between the labels. Can you increase the size of the plot?

Answer (score -1):

You could increase the interval between labels from 3 to 5. (I had to construct fake data to be able to plot).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(402, 630)
Quickdatres = [str(_) if _%5==0 else '' for _ in x]
y = np.random.randint(500, 3000, 630-402)

line = plt.figure()    
plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', marker='o', color='b')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(x, Quickdatres, rotation="vertical")

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.xaxis.get_children()[1].set_size(100)
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:  
    label.set_visible(False)   

plt.show()
```

[image]